# Difference between "legacy contao module" and (just) "contao module"

Tags: module, composer-php, contao

Does somebody now the difference between "legacy contao module" and (just) "contao module"? Why do these two types of modules exist and what should we use (in which situation)?

[image: Difference between "legacy contao module" and (just) "contao module"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The legacy modules are ported from the old extension repository of contao to a packagist. This is a special service of the contao community alliance to offer the possibility to install extension via composer that are not available at packagist. Generally, the modules from legacy are older. If there is a "normal" contao module, use this.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! If "normal" is the first choice then the Package List Sorting should take that into account and should first list "normal" and after these the legacy module. It seems to me that currently there is an alphabetic sorting implemented. Anyway ... your answer is very helpful!

Comment: Yes, the list is ordered alphabetically. But normally when you try to install a legacy module that has already a correct managed module at packagist, you get a hint like this: [composer hint](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CMzf9ByWUAAd_qG.jpg:large)

Comment: Helpfull comment! Indeed in case of "rocksolid-frontend-helper" there is no such hint. Maybe it makes sence to implement this sort nonetheless.